# How to get this result for this integral computation?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I do not understand how to get the following:
$$
\sum_{\lvert m\rvert <N}(1-\frac{\lvert m\rvert}{N})f(m)\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{i(h-m)v}\, dv=\begin{cases}(1-\frac{\lvert h\rvert}{N})f(h), & \lvert h\rvert <N\\0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

Do you see that and can please explain that to me?

I have no idea, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i(h-m)v} \, dv = \begin{cases} 2\pi & h=m \\ 0 & h \neq m \end{cases} $$
It follows that, if $\lvert h \rvert \geqslant N$, there is no term in the sum for which the integral is nonzero. On the other hand, if $\lvert h \rvert <N$, then the above identity gives $2\pi$ of the term with $m=h$, which is (almost) what you've got. (The discrepancy's not my error; did you copy something down incompletely?)

Comment: Yes, sorry. I forgot the factor $1/(2\pi)$ in front of the sum.